# Rake db:migrate error - SQLite3

Tags: dbmigrate

I keep getting the following error when doing the rake db:migrate command:

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

I've also tried the command  -  bundle exec rake db:migrate.  I ran with --trace and got the info. below.

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  AddDeviseToUsers: migrating ===============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in`execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in`block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in`log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:264:in`add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:400:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:479:in`block in string'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:468:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:468:in`string'
/Users/ddorrick/code/onrails/db/migrate/20130321170702_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:243:in`change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in`block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in`say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in`method_missing'
/Users/ddorrick/code/onrails/db/migrate/20130321170702_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in`up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in`measure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in`with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in`migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in`call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in`transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in`ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in`up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in`block (2 levels) in '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in`block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in`execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in`invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in`top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in`standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in`'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in`'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all, if you're using devise for authentication,email field is provided by default. The source for the error is: "The email field is also present in users table. That's why whenever you're run db:migrate it shows duplicate column error.

So drop the users table by giving command ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:users)"  in rails console.

Then, give  rails g model user user_name:string mobile_number:integer

Hope it will helps.
```